# Vastu Shastra --reason

Tags: surya, vastu-shastra

I recently got interested in vastu. I know something related to sun being there in the East but what about the other directions.

Also I learnt that adding a new built room is not good without puja. what is the reason behind this ?

pls answer the second one

Comment: Scientific speculations are off topic. If you want answer only from scientific perspectives then the question might get closed

Comment: Each direction has directional deities.. Like Yama is associated with south.. Nritti (goddess of destruction) with south west... Varuna with west... likewise Lord Ishana for the most auspicious direction (North East) ... thus worship places are generally built towards North East.. water related things kept West (due to Varuna)... Pitri related in southern direction and so on... there is a concept of Vastu Purusha which encompasses the whole house.. the head of Vastu Purusha is in North East... (thus toilets etc not built there).. respective places designed in the body parts of Vastu Purusha...

Comment: To understand Vastu scientifically, first understand Einstein's Space-Time continuum. Space & Time are not separate domains rather single flow. How are space and time understood in Vedic spirituality? Space is Vastu and Time is Jyotish and both work together through Astro-Vastu.Everyone knows that body is made of 5 elements Space, Air, Fire, Water, Earth but how does it work practically?If we live on Earth & take light from Sun, what is the need of planets like Jupiter, Saturn, Mars, Venus etc.,?These are all encrypted elements/strings ruling Vastu directions and Horoscope dashas for everyone.

Comment: ya now pls answer the second part.pls

Comment: vivikta. ya mean that really..?
the sanatan dharma is completely scientific.
literally  sanatan dharma is the postulate that science is trying to prove.

Comment: you should edit and remove the line: "What is the scientific reason of all"

Comment: why do think so,
everything is completely scientific and logical sanatan dharma is completely scientific 
whats the problem

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by " scientific reason "? Do you mean logical philosophical reasons, like Devatas in different directions and effect of Panchabhutas, or you mean explanation from modern science?.. If you say modern science, it will be speculation as modern science doesn't talk about Vastu.. If former, edit question asking philosophical reason..

Comment: yeah the philosophical reason you can say

Comment: @chittaranjanrout Please edit question saying same because Scientific reason might mean modern science..

Comment: done now pls answer my question 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vastu Shastra and Jyotish Shastra are part of [Apara knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Para_Vidya) and can be truly understood, only after realizing Brahman Gyan or Atman gyan, not through modern extroverted material science.

> Saunaka, having asked – कस्मिन्नु भगवो विज्ञाते सर्वमिदं विज्ञातं
> भवतीति (" Revered Sir, what is that by the knowing of which all this
> becomes known? "), - was told by Angiras that –
>
> द्वे विद्ये वेदितव्ये इति ह् स्म यद्ब्रह्मविदो वदन्ति परा चैवापरा च |
> तत्रापरा ऋग्वेदो यजुर्वेदः सामवेदोऽथर्ववेदः शिक्षा कल्पो व्याकरणं
> निरुक्तं छन्दो ज्योतिषमिति | अथ परा यया तदक्षरमधिग्म्यते || - (Mundaka
> Upanishad I.i.3-5)
>
> there were two different kinds of knowledge to be acquired – 'the
> higher knowledge' or Para Vidya (Sanskrit: परा विद्या )and 'the lower
> knowledge' or Apara Vidya. **The lower knowledge consists of all textual
> knowledge - the four Vedas, the science of pronunciation etc., the
> code of rituals, grammar, etymology, metre and astrology. The higher
> knowledge is by which the immutable and the imperishable Atman is
> realized, which knowledge brings about the direct realization of the
> Supreme Reality, the source of All.** The knowledge of the Atman is very
> subtle; it cannot be obtained out of one's own effort; the Atman
> cannot be intuitively apprehended by mere intellectual equipments.
> Thus, Angiras draws the distinction between the way of knowledge and
> the way of realization, as between opinion and truth. For
> understanding this for realizing the Reality the aspirant must seek a
> teacher. **The teacher who has already realized his identity with the
> Atman alone can impart this much sought-after wisdom on the strength
> of his own experiences.**

[image]

Anyways, in layman terms, **Vastu Shastra is based on 5 elements or [Panch bhuta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancha_Bhoota)** :- Space, Air, Fire, Water and Earth, which are the core of entire universe. Just like recent inventions of mobile phones, computers and other electrical appliances have a fixed way of working with electricity, charging and containing predefined applications/operations, similarly this projected Maya or universe has basic fixed rules like Sun will always rise in East and sets in West. Since, Sun rises in East, therefore most of sunlight shines and radiates in Northern and Eastern side of a house, thats why according to Vastu, bedroom should be build in Southern or Western side, as sleep is possible only at night and darkness and Sun is weakest in the Western direction and therefore that region of house(South-West) is best for master bedroom.

[image]

Use of house's different directions for different purposes like NE for house temple, SE for kitchen actually comes from zodiacal belt of 27 constellations/Nakshatras as explained in [Vishvakarma Prakash](https://archive.org/details/vishwakarma-prakash/page/n9/mode/2up). So, to truly understand Vastu Shastra, Jyotish Shastra should be studied parallelly. For example, **house temple is recommended to be constructed in North-East of house because directly above it(for any plot) in the sky lies the [Kritika constellation](https://www.rahasyavedicastrology.com/krittika-nakshatra/) which is the first constellation of zodiac belt and represents small Fire/Agni(personified as Kartikeya/Murugan in temples)** as the beginning of the Universe. Similarly, bedroom is recommended to be built in the South direction because directly above is the [Uttara Phalguni constellation](https://www.rahasyavedicastrology.com/uttara-phalguni/) which is symbolized with bed and is in middle of Fire(Passion)-Earth(Sleep) elements, dominance of these two basic elements are necessary for any common man to function properly in earthly society. Medicines should be kept in NNE of house to improve their efficiency as directly above it is the [Ashwini constellation](https://www.rahasyavedicastrology.com/ashwini-nakshatra/), which is personified as Ashwini Kumaras, the healer doctor Gods. Washroom with water(not Toilet) should be built in Eastern direction, because above it in sky is the [Ardra Nakshatra](https://www.rahasyavedicastrology.com/ardra-nakshatra/) which is personified as Rudra God(full of tear rains). Toilet should be build in SSW as above it is the [Swati nakshatra](https://www.rahasyavedicastrology.com/swati-nakshatra/)(ruled by Vayu). Churning equipments like washing machine or motors should be placed in ESE direction i.e. below [Ashlesha](https://www.rahasyavedicastrology.com/ashlesha-nakshatra/) nakshatra(ruled by Nagas) which represents snakes and thats why Vasuki snake was used to churn ocean during [Samudra Manthan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samudra_manthan).

Construction of wrong things at wrong directions lead to catastrophic effects over long terms **like building toilet(representing Rahu) in North-East(head of Vastu Purusha) can lead to brain diseases and insomnia, building kitchen in North-East can lead to anger issues or high bp problem** in one or more than one person of a family living in a house made with wrong Vastu.

[image]

[image]

So, in conclusion **Vastu Shastra and Jyotisha Shastra are controlled by 33 Vedic Gods** i.e. **28 static Purusha Nakshatra Gods**(including Abhijeet nakshatra)+ **5 dynamic Prakriti elements/planets**(Space(Jupiter), Air(Saturn), Fire(Mars), Water(Venus) and Earth(Mercury))

Comment: please answer the second part of my question.

Comment: @chittaranjanrout Puja is futile if doing wrong construction. There are many Vastu rules, first the purpose of room and its direction is to be seen. Adding room with bathroom in North-East or North or East can be dangerous. As hammering while constructing in the region of vastu purush head's(NE) or building toilet in NE can lead to health issues within people living in house. Another problem is to be seen regarding disturbing symmetry of house , as best house is square or max ratio of rectangle with lxb(2:1). Also see monthly muhurat for construction.